# Slick2D weird bug, Music(String ref, boolean streamingHint) only works for a second then stops

Tags: java, game-development, slick2d, openal, ogg

Yesterday I
I found a way to NOT load music files to memory, instead just [stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOFzm.png) the file directly through the disk, but it only works for a second, take note that making

```
streamingHint = false;
```

loads it to memory, which making load times slower, which I don't like to happen... but it fixes the problem...

I do not believe in the saying "if it works, do not touch it", but in regards to optimization, this wasn't the case... but if there is no possible fix, I'm going to switch on something else cuz this lib was so outdated, or just accept loading it to the memory...

[video proof](https://youtu.be/S1m3h3A614A)

here's the code:

```
package johnkennedypena;

import org.newdawn.slick.Music;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

public class DebugStreamingHint {
    Music music;

    public DebugStreamingHint() throws SlickException {
        music = new Music("resources_/music_/music_.ogg", true);
        music.play();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, SlickException {
        new DebugStreamingHint();
        Thread.sleep(100000);
    }
}
```

I'm using Windows... My JDK version was Java 8... I use IntelliJ as IDE...

Comment: Is it necessary for your case to use custom class, that don't extend BasicGame or StateBasedGame from Slick?

Comment: Your code truly behaves as you say, but if you use, for example, BasicGame, music works as it supposed to (I wrote a simple [example](https://pastebin.com/En3hQ67m), try it)

Comment: @OldTeaOwl i only need the BasicGame to start, i do not need the AppGameContainer, is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package johnkennedypena;

import org.lwjgl.Sys;
import org.newdawn.slick.Music;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

public class DebugStreamingHint {
    Music music;

    public DebugStreamingHint(String title) throws SlickException {
        lastFrame = getTime();
        music = new Music("resources_/music_/reminds me of elevators.ogg", true);
        music.play();
        while (true){
            int delta = getDelta();
            Music.poll(delta);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, SlickException {
        new DebugStreamingHint("");
    }

    // making int delta a thing
    long lastFrame;
    public int getDelta() {
        long time = getTime();
        int delta = (int) (time - lastFrame);
        lastFrame = time;
        return delta;
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return (Sys.getTime() * 1000) / Sys.getTimerResolution();
    }
}
```

I figured it out! I found Music.poll(int delta) by digging through the slick2d source.

Thanks *@OldTeaOwl*.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm glad that you've figured it out!